How to plot mutltiple geometries in correct projection by geoplot?
I use code as below to plot multiple geometries:
newGdf = gpd.read_file(os.path.abspath(newFile), driver='KML')
oldGdf = gpd.read_file(os.path.abspath(oldFile), driver='KML')

lonMean, LagMean = newGdf.centroid.get_coordinates().mean()
proj = geoplot.crs.Orthographic(central_longitude=lonMean, central_latitude=LagMean)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(18, 10.5), subplot_kw={"projection": proj})
ax.set_aspect('equal')

newPolyGdf = newGdf[newGdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, Polygon))]
newLineGdf = newGdf[newGdf.geometry.type=='LineString']
geoplot.polyplot(newPolyGdf, ax=ax, facecolor=color, zorder=2)
geoplot.polyplot(newLineGdf, ax=ax, facecolor='none', color='blue', zorder=3)

oldPolyGdf = oldGdf[oldGdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, Polygon))]
oldLineGdf = oldGdf[oldGdf.geometry.type=='LineString']
geoplot.polyplot(oldPolyGdf, ax=ax, facecolor=color, zorder=2)
geoplot.polyplot(oldLineGdf, ax=ax, facecolor='none', color='blue', zorder=3)

You can see the post plot oldGdf LineString is not correct, I think the reason is the projection is used from the newGdf, how can I let both line in correct projection?

The error when do transoform before proj, plot result as below if transform after proj:


Answer to this will be full blog post explaining the Projections, CRS etc. In short while working with Projections use PyProj for Projection transformations.
Code sample for shapely do a transformation:
# change to metric system
project_to_3857 = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326'), # source coordinate system
    pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3857')) # destination coordinate system

polygon = shapely.ops.transform(project_to_4326.transform, polygon)

PyProj PyPi Link

Thanks for your code what I need, I can read theory by myself. By the way, can I just transform proj = geoplot.crs.Orthographic(central_longitude=lonMean, central_latitude=LagMean) instead of polygon?

polygon = shapely.ops.transform(project_to_4326.transform, polygon) is polygon = shapely.ops.transform(project_to_3857.transform, polygon)?

I got error `Exception has occurred: ValueError
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
File "C:\myPython\myPlot.py", line 464, in getImageFromKml
newGdf = transform(project_to_3857.transform, newGdf)

Transform only works on Geometries not gdf, so first extract Geometries from gdf, then  do transformations, then reload gdf with new geometry.

polygon = shapely.ops.transform(project_to_4326.transform, polygon) is polygon = shapely.ops.transform(project_to_3857.transform, polygon)?
Yes, but with different projections

Thanks for your code what I need, I can read theory by myself. By the way, can I just transform proj = geoplot.crs.Orthographic(central_longitude=lonMean, central_latitude=LagMean) instead of polygon?
No, First create Point Geometry from lat-lng

Do I have to transform geometries before or after proj = geoplot.crs.Orthographic(central_longitude=lonMean, central_latitude=LagMean)? I tried two ways, there is error tarnsform before proj, plot results is not what I wonder.
